# Add Textbox title in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, title

**How to assign value to "title" attribute for text box in Jquery ?**
I have searched in Internet , but am not getting the result.
Answer will be appreciated

Comment: Oh mY God .. Who doesn't understand my question ? Why -1?. Even i got the answer . but which person doesnt get the question

Comment: This will help you in accessing html elements http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: yeah i know . i cant able to accept the answer. only after 10 minutes only i can be able to accept it. so please wait freebird

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jQuery `attr()` method documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

```
$('input').attr('title', 'your value');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bFw2h/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `jquery` `.attr()` method to change any attribute of the element.
`$('#txtbox').attr('title','My Title');` will assign `title` to your `textbox`.

**[See Live sample](http://jsfiddle.net/DJrmX/)**

Answer (score 3):

Any attribute can be set or added with `jQuery`:

```
$(selector).attr('attribute-name', 'attribute-value')
```

So, adding `title` to a `textbox`:

```
$('input[type="text"]').attr('title', 'hello');
```